# how to change data type sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to change a column from  identity(1,1) NOT null to  INT NOT NULL?

What is the SQL command to alter this table?

i already try but not success , the data still auto increment.

Comment: Create a #temp_table and insert all the records from your main table to #temp_table.. then drop and create your main table (remove the identity) then insert all the record from #temp_table to your main table.. edit> dont forget to drop #temp_table after inserting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After altering your column datatype you need to set Identity insert to on for you table, like below.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTableName ON
```

After this you should be able to insert your values on the column that was an Identity column.